# Batch compiling C# code for WinRT and Windows x86

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

I recently published a library targeted to build for .Net4.5. Now that Windows 8 is out, I'd like to essentially build for that platform too.

Unfortunately, some of the code I used in the original library hasn't made it into the RT core, however I've spent most of today doing the adjustments and testing with a copy of the code.

Essentially I've now got two code files, an original, and a copy with about 5 lines updated and using a different namespace. I've done conditional compilation for Debug/Release, however I've never done a batch compile.

My ideal goal would be to combine these files, perhaps using compiler flags and `#if`, to make the code more manageable. Then compile to Library.WinRT.dll and Library.x86.dll. I don't mind having 2 different projects, symbolically linking the files, but I really don't want duplicate code.

Any suggestions on how I can go about doing this? Anyone got experiences they'd like to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered your own question. Use compiler flags, link to files between projects (not using the file system's symbolic links, but rather add existing files from one project to the other as link - using the drop down next to the "Add" button in the open file dialog). What do you mean by batch compile? Do you want to build from command line? Then you can do something like this:

```
msbuild /verbosity:quiet /fl /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release Library.WinRT\Library.WinRT.csproj
msbuild /verbosity:quiet /fl /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release Library.NET45\Library.NET45.csproj
```